# ignore the exception and load data into snowflake

Tags: exception, error-handling, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In snowflake, I am able to get the error details using TRY-CATCH method.
I mocked up a data where I am trying to insert a VARCHAR data into INTEGER data type column.
This exception was caught in try-catch method used in my snowflake procedure. As usual, the procedure failed and none of the records were inserted. I want to ignore this BAD data and insert rest of the records into my target table using snowflake procedure. IS THIS POSSIBLE?
Also I need to INSERT that BAD data into another table. How can we achieve this?
Please share you thoughts/expertise.
Thanks, Joe.

Comment: You can probably use IFF to validate if the data is of the type you want as explained [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/iff.html)

Comment: @Serigu -- thanks for the input. in my case IFF wont work.. it is something i am trying to check for a specific value. In my case, my data type itself is different. Also mine is a JSON format src value where i will have to do the validation.
My Need ---> I want to route such data into a separate table and continue with the load. So that i can work on the bad data later. Can this be achieved in TRY-CATCH method in SF Procedures.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Snowflake procedure/ function you can write a common Error routine in captures the errors in a table and call it in your procedure. Please check this link for a common error handler which i wrote few months back.

https://github.com/hkandpal/Snowflake/blob/main/Snow_Erro_Handling.txt

Comment: Thanks for the script. I went through it. Sorry, this will not serve my purpose. My need is, I wanted to log the bad data (inserting varchar data into integer column) and continue with the existing load.

Comment: Hi you can use TRY_TO_NUMBER function which will insert the value NULL if the data is not integer.

Comment: Thanks Himanshu. Yes this is an option, but i would need to inspect the data later. If we use TRY_TONUMBER, the data will be updated and loaded into table, right? But, i need to load and work on it after the load is complete.

Answer (score 0):

> *I am trying to insert a VARCHAR data into INTEGER data type column.*
>
> *I want to ignore this BAD data and insert rest of the records into my target table using snowflake procedure*

If the source is VARCHAR then assumption that it contain INTEGER may be dangerous. Instead of trying to insert incorrect data and fail entire query alternative approach could validate data. [TRY_CAST](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_cast.html):

> A special version of CAST , :: that is available for a subset of data type conversions. It performs the same operation (i.e. converts a value of one data type into another data type), but **returns a NULL value instead of raising an error when the conversion can not be performed.**

```
-- pass only NULLs and validated rows
INSERT INTO tab(col_int)
SELECT col_varchar
FROM source_table
WHERE TRY_CAST(col_varchar AS INT) IS NOT NULL
   OR col_varchar IS NULL;

-- error table, log 
INSERT INTO error_table(col_varchar)
SELECT col_varchar
FROM source_table
WHERE TRY_CAST(col_varchar AS INT) IS NULL
  AND col_varchar IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Lukasz. Using this may degrade the performance as my data is variant and I am flattening.  But let me try. Do you have any info on what all options can be tried in try-catch method.